# Batch: Insert lines from dat file into dat file by order

Tags: batch-file

I have a 500 piece of dat files and I can add the lines below by using batch file below. The problem is after adding lines into the dat file, new dat file  line order is turning to crash as you'll see below. Are there any command to fix this?

This is my dat file: (Line_to_add.dat file is similar as below.)

```
Sample
  VarType = REG_DWORD 0x3
  Data = "7"
  Properties
    Label_D = "German Version"
    Label_E = "English Version"
X
```

This is my batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (123.dat) DO (
  ECHO %%A
  IF "%%A" EQU "X" (
    TYPE line_to_add.dat
  )
) >> C:\Users\myaccount\Desktop\Paste\new\123.dat
```

After running the batch, the line order is going wrong. But the lines from line_to_add.dat is ok.

```
VSSProg3
VarType = REG_DWORD 0x3
Data = "7"
Properties
Label_D = "German Version"
Label_E = "English Version"
X

New
  VarType = REG_DWORD 0x3
  Data = "0"
  Properties
    Label_D = "German Version"
    Label_E = "English Version"
X
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `"delims="` in place of `"tokens=*"` as the latter deletes leading spaces.